# Sum of decimal in null list causing exception

Tags: c#, linq, sum, decimal

I have the following bit of code which is causing an exception when no data is found.

```
decimal expectedAmount = salePayments.Where(x => x.PaymentTypeId == i).Select(x => x.Amount).Sum(x => x);
```

The exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The cast to value type 'Decimal' failed
>   because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's
>   generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

A bit of research on SO led me to try:

```
decimal? test = salePayments.Where(x => x.PaymentTypeId==i).Select(x => x.Amount).Sum(x => x) ?? 0m;
```

But this now wont compile with the error:

> Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'decimal'.

Answer (score 6):

You need to explicitly cast `x.Amount` in `Select` to `decimal?` and then you can use null coalescing operator.

```
decimal test = salePayments.Where(x => x.PaymentTypeId==i)
                            .Select(x => (decimal?) x.Amount).Sum(x => x) ?? 0m;
```

Or you can get `decimal` back like:

```
decimal test = salePayments.Where(x => x.PaymentTypeId==i)
                            .Select(x => x.Amount ?? 0m).Sum(x => x);
```

I am not sure about that, but you can try applying `Sum` directly like:

```
decimal? test = salePayments.Where(x => x.PaymentTypeId==i)
                                .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

According to [documentation,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383052%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) this would return 0, if the list is empty.

Comment: It appears to be Entity Framework. There are two relevant overloads, [`Queryable.Sum<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, Decimal>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534801.aspx) and [`Queryable.Sum<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource, Nullable<Decimal>>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549409.aspx). I am no expert in EF, but why does `.Amount` appear to have compile-time C# type which is non-nullable, while at the same time the column in the database has `NULL` entries? If the types in C# and SQL had agreed, the overload would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Add a DefaultIfEmpty(0.0M) prior to the .Sum